# Conditional Class inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Alright, so I'm developing an app for Windows 8.1 Universal and there's some API's on the phone that doesn't exist on the PC Platform. The thing is I'm trying to Inherit a class conditionally if the current platform is the windows phone. here's a snippet of my code (THAT DOES NOT WORK)

```
    public class Client : IDisposable, IClient
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        , IWebAuthenticationContinuable
#endif
    {
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args) { }
#endif

        public void DoStuff()
        {

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
```

whenever i try to create a new instance of this class in my view model i get the following error:
Cannot create instance of type 'App87.ViewModels.MainViewModel' [Line: 9 Position: 27]

Line 9 is my constructor which only creates a new instance of the Client class.

Comment: Not enough context. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: This class doesn't have any methods or properties and it doesn't even have a constructor. so my code snippet contain all the code from the class.

Comment: Doesn't it have methods that implement the interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried your exact code, there is only one thing that isn't working: `ContinueWebAuthentication` should be marked as public since it's inherited from an interface:

```
public interface IClient { }

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
public interface IWebAuthenticationContinuable
{
    void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args);
}
#endif

public class Client : IDisposable, IClient
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    , IWebAuthenticationContinuable
#endif
{
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    public void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args) { }
#endif

    public void DoStuff()
    {

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This wasn't working for me, so I opened a new Universal project and tried it, and it worked just fine. But it still not working in the old project. I guess it's a visual studio thing.